# Firebase Dynamic Link service -- I can't understand exactly what it's about

Tags: links, url-shortening, goo.gl

I read the news that Google has shut down his short linker service goo.gl and the fact that FDL APIs will be used instead. And I've watched a video about the matter. However, I still can't comprehend how the  Firebase Dynamic Link service better than that goo.gl? Can anyone give me real world examples of using it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have been creating links by going to goo.gl then Google recommend using an alternative service, FDL is targeted at developers.

For developers, the advantage of FDL is that it can link to a mobile app as well as a website. For example an FDL shortened Twitter link will open twitter.com if used in a browser, but will open the Twitter app if used on an Android phone. In this way the links are "smart".

Comment: how is that smartness achieved?

Comment: mostly by looking at the user-agent

Comment: are there other advantages of Firebase Dynamic Link?

Comment: The [FDL product page](https://firebase.google.com/products/dynamic-links/) has a pitch for the advantages, but it largely boils down to the fact they can link into apps.

Comment: how is a link able to launch an app on your smartphone at all?

Comment: If the app implements a custom URI scheme it can register to open when that URI is accessed - for example, doco for Android [is here](https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/)